# Compiler error C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Trying to debug my program and getting some error's I cannot figure out.

```
CruiseShip.h: In constructor ‘CruiseShip::CruiseShip(std::string, std::string, int)’:
CruiseShip.h:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
CruiseShip.h:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
CruiseShip.h:16: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
CruiseShip.cpp: At global scope:
CruiseShip.cpp:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘n’
CruiseShip.cpp: In function ‘void print()’:
CruiseShip.cpp:20: error: ‘passengers’ was not declared in this scope
```

**CruiseShip.h**

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H
    #define CRUISESHIP_H
    #include "Ship.h"
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    //class Ship;

    class CruiseShip:public Ship{
        private:
            int passengers;
            Ship::Ship s;
        public:


            CruiseShip(string, string, int):Ship(string,string);

        virtual void print();
    };

    #endif
```

**CruiseShip.cpp**

```
  #include "CruiseShip.h"
    #include "Ship.h"

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    Ship s;


      CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)
      {
        passengers=p;
      }

       void print()
       {
        cout<<"Name: "<<s.getName()<<"\nMaximum passengers:"<<passengers<<endl;
      cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
       }
```

Comment: You probably should consult a [good book about some basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or tutorial before asking your next question. The system bans for asking poor questions pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to and mustn't declare initializer list.

Try changing

```
CruiseShip(string, string, int):Ship(string,string);
```

to

```
CruiseShip(string, string, int);
```

Comment: Okay makes sense, thanks buddy!